# Python Instagram Auto logger

Tags: python, logging, instagram

I just trying to make a python API which log automatically me on my instagram page, but it seems that the program does not recognize the box in which it has to put my email address and my password. I used the function that find the element by the xpath.
I copied the xpath from Instagram but it doesn't work.

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
chromedriver = "C:\\Users\\Utente\\Desktop\\chromedriver" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

usr = input ("Enter Your Email: ")
psw = getpass("Enter Your Password: ")
prfl = input('Enter the exactly name of the profile you want the picture: ')

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")

login_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[2]/p/a')
login_elem.click() 


inputs = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]')

ActionChains(driver)\
.move_to_element(inputs[0])\
.click()\
.send_keys(usr)\
.move_to_element(inputs[1])\
.send_keys(psw)\
.perform() 

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/button')
ActionChains(driver)\
.move_to_element(login_button)\
.click()\
.perform()


codio = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]')
actions = ActionChains(driver)\
.move_to_element(codio)\
.click()\
.send_keys(prfl)\
.perform()
```

[Here the xpath i copied from instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta5QB.png)

[Here the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lJGd.png)

Comment: Can you post code and error message as text, please?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nothing in your post is useful. You don't describe the problem, you don't explain what you tried that didnt work, you don't describe what the output should look like. Please read the help section and learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: im sorry @dfundako i've never posted a question before.

Comment: @Austin i will put another question with the code as text hopefully will be usefull for you to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewrote your code a little bit and it works now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chromedriver = "C:\\Users\\Utente\\Desktop\\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

usr = input ("Enter Your Email: ")
psw = getpass("Enter Your Password: ")
prfl = input('Enter the exactly name of the profile you want the picture: ')

driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="username"]'))).send_keys(usr)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="password"]').send_keys(psw)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Log in")]').click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Profile"]')))
```

I'm using explicit waits to make the code more stable.

Hope, this will help you to learn how selenium works.

Comment: sure. did it :D

Comment: Another thing, when i log on my page there is a pop up witch ask me if i want to receive notifications, i copied the xpath of the button wich refuses. The code is this: wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]'))).click(). But it does not work could you explain me why if you can? Thank you very much.

Comment: Browser gives xpath that doesn't work. I'm writing my own xpath.
Try this one to decline notifications: //button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]

Comment: oh ok i understand, it does not work anyway but thank you very much